# My codeigniter update function not working

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I have simple code to update data, but unfortunately it didn't work at all. Only show blank page without any error message. The query for my index and view edit run well. But not for update Please help me.

**this is my models : ModelSiswa.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use \CodeIgniter\Model;

class ModelSiswa extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_user';
    protected $allowedFields = ['nama_user', 'alamat', 'tgl', 'hp', 'email'];
    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';
    protected $returnType = 'array';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

This is my controller :
**Siswa.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\ModelSiswa;

class Siswa extends BaseController
{

     public function index()
    {

        $model = new ModelSiswa();
        $data['siswa'] = $model->findAll();
        return view('viewSiswa', $data);
    }

     public function editSiswa($id = null)
    {
        $model = new ModelSiswa();

        $data['siswa'] = $model->where('id_user', $id)->first();

        return view('siswa_edit_view', $data);
    }
     public function updat()
    {

        $model = new ModelSiswa();
        $id = $this->request->getVar('id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $data = [

            'nama_user' => $this->request->getVar('nama_user'),
            'alamat'  => $this->request->getVar('alamat'),
            'tgl'  => $this->request->getVar('tgl'),
            'hp'  => $this->request->getVar('hp'),
            'email'  => $this->request->getVar('email')
        ];
         if ($this->model->update($id, $data)) {
            return $this->response->redirect(base_url('siswa'));
        } else {
            return $this->response->redirect(base_url('siswa/editsiswa/' . $id));
        }

    }
```

**this is my index view : viewSiswa.php**

```
            <?php if (count($siswa) > 0) : ?>
                <table class='table'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Nama</th>
                        <th>Alamat</th>
                        <th>No HP</th>
                        <th>Tgl Lahir</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Created</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php foreach ($siswa as $emp) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $emp['id_user']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $emp['nama_user']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $emp['alamat']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $emp['hp']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $emp['tgl']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $emp['email']; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $emp['created_at']; ?></td>
                            <td>

                                <a href='<?= base_url(); ?>/siswa/editsiswa/<?= $emp['id_user'] ?>'>Edit</a>
                                <a href='<?= base_url(); ?>/siswa/delete/<?= $emp['id_user'] ?>'>Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

This is my View update **siswa_edit_view.php**

```
    <form method="post" action="<?= base_url() . '/siswa/updat'; ?>">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Siswa</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nama</label>
                <input type="text" name="nama_user" id="edit_nama" class="form-control" value="<?= $siswa['nama_user']; ?>" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Alamat</label>
                <input type="text" name="alamat" id="edit_alamat" class="form-control" value="<?= $siswa['alamat']; ?>" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>No HP</label>
                <input type="number" name="hp" id="edit_hp" class="form-control" value="<?= $siswa['hp']; ?>" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tgl Lahir</label>
                <input type="text" name="tgl" id="edit_tgl" class="form-control" value="<?= $siswa['tgl']; ?>" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="edit_email" class="form-control" value="<?= $siswa['email']; ?>" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="edit_id" value="<?= $siswa['id_user']; ?>" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-dark rounded-0 col-2" href="<?= base_url("/siswa") ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Back to List</a>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Update">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Blank page typically means your environment is not configured in development mode.

Comment: already in development mode. I've test with error and show up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I've forgot to handle my address filter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).